# how to increment aplha numeric number field in awk

Tags: awk

i want to incerement M152DHD3H4M2 this number.

output like

```
M152DHD3H4M3
M152DHD3H4M4
M152DHD3H4M5
M152DHD3H4M6
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Method 1: Treat each character as a separate field

```
$ echo 'M152DHD3H4M2' | awk -F "" '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {$NF++;print}}' OFS=
M152DHD3H4M3
M152DHD3H4M4
M152DHD3H4M5
M152DHD3H4M6
```

`-F ""` tells awk to treat each character as  separate field on input and `OFS=` tells awk not to add any field separator on output.  We then increment the last field as desired.

`$NF++` increments the value in the last field.

An empty field separator like this is not required by POSIX but is supported by at least by GNU awk and mawk.

#### Method 2:  Use `M` as a field separator

```
$ echo 'M152DHD3H4M2' | awk -FM '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++) {$NF++;print}}' OFS=M
M152DHD3H4M3
M152DHD3H4M4
M152DHD3H4M5
M152DHD3H4M6
```

`-FM` and `OFS=M` tells awk to use `M` as the field separator on both input and output.  We then increment the last field as desired.

#### Method 3: Divide the string into parts using `substr`

```
$ echo 'M152DHD3H4M2' | awk '{for(i=1;i<=4;i++) print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1) i+substr($1, length($1))}'
M152DHD3H4M3
M152DHD3H4M4
M152DHD3H4M5
M152DHD3H4M6
```

Here we break the input line manually using the substring function, `substr`, and increment the last character as desired.

Comment: +1. It would be even better if the value was incremented from the input, instead of being hard-coded in the for loop!

Comment: @StephenKitt You're right about that.  The first two approaches weren't strictly incrementing.   I just updated to fix that.